# Tree merge algorithm in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tree

I need a function which takes two trees, checks to see if there are any common branches coming off the trunk, and merges the trees into a single tree if possible.

Nodes can be considered the same if their `rootLabels` are equal. Two trees with different roots cannot be merged. Two trees with the same root can be merged, and their branches can be recursively checked to see if they can be merged.

Can anyone suggest an implementation for the function `merge`(below) which passes `test1` and `test2` (i.e. functions return `True`)? I'm sure there is a simple, elegant solution, but it is evading me at the moment. Alternatively, is there an existing library function I can use?

```
import Data.Tree

merge :: (Eq a) => Tree a -> Tree a -> Either (Tree a, Tree a) (Tree a)
merge = undefined

test1 :: Bool
test1 = 
    Node 'a' 
            [Node 'b' 
                [Node 'c' 
                    [], 
                Node 'g' 
                    []], 
            Node 'd' 
                []]
    `merge`
    Node 'a' 
            [Node 'b' 
                [Node 'c' 
                    [Node 'h'
                        []]], 
            Node 'e' 
                [Node 'f' 
                    []]]
    == 
    Right 
    (Node 'a' 
        [Node 'b' 
            [Node 'c' 
                [Node 'h'
                    []], 
            Node 'g' 
                []], 
        Node 'd' 
            [],
        Node 'e' 
            [Node 'f' 
                []]])

test2 :: Bool
test2 =  
    let l = Node 'a' []
        r = Node 'b' []
    in  l `merge` r == Left (l,r)
```

Comment: So if the root is common but the branches are not, what happens?

Comment: @n.m. Then the result would be a single tree with the common root, and all of the branches from both of the original trees. If you see `test1`, the left tree has a branch 'd' which is not in the right tree. The result contains all branches from both trees, including branch 'd'.

Comment: @DanielWagner I haven't yet got a solution which passes type checks

Comment: Show what you've got anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've finally got it;

```
merge :: (Eq a) => Tree a -> Tree a -> Either (Tree a, Tree a) (Tree a)
merge l r = 
    if rootLabel l == rootLabel r
        then Right $ merge' l r 
        else Left (l,r)

merge' :: (Eq a) => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
merge' l r = l { subForest = foldl mergeNode (subForest l) (subForest r) }

mergeNode :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> Tree a -> [Tree a]
mergeNode [] y = [y]
mergeNode (x:xs) y 
    | rootLabel x == rootLabel y = x `merge'` y : xs
    | otherwise = x : xs `mergeNode` y
```